# build node set dynamically based on input xml with xslt1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

When using the xslt document() function. Reading for example following xml:

```
<Products>
    <Product productCode="SQUARE-BLUE-EXTRA-A-10-MAY" messageType="FOUNTAIN" messageTag="F"/>
    <Product productCode="SQUARE-RED-EXTRA-B-20-JUNE" messageType="FOUNTAIN" messageTag="F"/>
</Products>
```

The output is a node-set which can be stored in a variable.
Instead of reading a xml document i want to build this variable with a nodeset dynamically based upon a xml input.

example of a xml input:

```
<Root>
    <Object>
        <QuoteLineItems>
            <Object>
                <Product2Id>
                    <ProductCode>SQUARE</ProductCode>
                </Product2Id>
                <QuoteLineItems>
                    <Object>
                        <Product2Id>
                            <ProductCode>BLUE</ProductCode>
                        </Product2Id>
                        <QuoteLineItems>
                            <Object>
                                <ServiceDate>MAY</ServiceDate>
                                <attributes>
                                    <Object>
                                        <attributeuniquecode>ATTR_VOLUMEPERCENTAGE</attributeuniquecode>
                                        <attributedisplayname>Volume percentage</attributedisplayname>
                                        <value>10</value>
                                    </Object>
                                    <Object>
                                        <attributeuniquecode>ATTR_TYPE</attributeuniquecode>
                                        <attributedisplayname>Type</attributedisplayname>
                                        <value>A</value>
                                    </Object>
                                </attributes>
                                <Product2Id>
                                    <ProductCode>EXTRA</ProductCode>
                                </Product2Id>
                                <QuoteLineItems/>
                            </Object>
                        </QuoteLineItems>
                    </Object>
                    <Object>
                        <Product2Id>
                            <ProductCode>RED</ProductCode>
                        </Product2Id>
                        <QuoteLineItems>
                            <Object>
                                <ServiceDate>JUNE</ServiceDate>
                                <attributes>
                                    <Object>
                                        <attributeuniquecode>ATTR_VOLUMEPERCENTAGE</attributeuniquecode>
                                        <attributedisplayname>Volume percentage</attributedisplayname>
                                        <value>20</value>
                                    </Object>
                                    <Object>
                                        <attributeuniquecode>ATTR_TYPE</attributeuniquecode>
                                        <attributedisplayname>Type</attributedisplayname>
                                        <value>B</value>
                                    </Object>
                                </attributes>
                                <Product2Id>
                                    <ProductCode>EXTRA</ProductCode>
                                </Product2Id>
                                <QuoteLineItems/>
                            </Object>
                        </QuoteLineItems>
                    </Object>
                </QuoteLineItems>
            </Object>
        </QuoteLineItems>
    </Object>
</Root>
```

i want to do this because i have to check a certain input xml against a lookup list(first xml).
with further extension the lookup list with possible combinations would be endless. therefore i want to build the exact same lookup list based upon the input xml and put it in a variable with the same format as i would use the document() function.

i've been trying things on and off for the past hours but i can't find something decent. is this possible?

This is my current use of the document function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="products" select="document(file.xml)/Products/Product[@messageType=$messageType]/@productCode"/>
    <Messages>
        <xsl:for-each select="$products">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="initial" select="$root">
                <xsl:with-param name="productCode" select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Messages>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

as you can see i have a variable $products. that contains my whole lookup list. i can then apply a template for each product.
the second document is just my input xml. and i want to build a lookup list into a variable based on this input xml.

Comment: Can you show us your current use of the `document` function? If you do nothing but `document('file.xml')` you simply have a document node. It is not clear what you want to do with the second document.

Comment: i've updated the original question. is it any more clear now?

Comment: What is the output you want to create? It is not clear to me.

Comment: the output doesn't matter here. what i want is a variable with several products so that i can use for each 'product' on that variable. this variable has to be build with data from the input xml but with more or less the same structure as when i use the document() function on the first xml.

Comment: So you want to transform the longer, second sample to the same format as the first, shorter input sample?

Comment: not really.. apparantly my question isn't clear at all..
The xslt i show (last document) is the xslt i use.
the second sample is the input xml.
the first sample is a lookup list that i import as a variable into the xslt.

my current way of working is importing the first xml (lookup list).
then for each product in this lookup list i will execute some transformations on the second xml.

because the lookuplist is becoming endless with a new extension. i want to build the lookuplist dynamically based upon the input message.

Comment: Perhaps explain and show the code for "because the lookuplist is becoming endless with a new extension", that part is not clear at all.

Comment: well, the whole point of this xslt is splitting a message. at first there was only SQUARE-BLUE,SQUARE-BLUE-EXTRA, SQUARE-RED, SQUARE-RED-EXTRA to check on. this means 4 products in the lookuplist. now extra parameters needs to be checked on TYPE, PERCENTAGE and DATE. there are 7 different types. a percentage can be 1-100. and a date can be really everything. this means it has so many different combinations. SQUARE-RED-EXTRA-A-10-MAY is different then SQUARE-RED-EXTRA-A-9-MAY. therefore i only want to put the combinations that are present in the input to be in the lookuplist. makes sense?

Comment: if you want i can send you the original xslt, original input and original lookup list. i'm kinda with my hands in my hair because i don't know how to add these extra splitting parameters